# threading.Lock() passed in vs globally accessed

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

Is there a fundamental difference between the following code?
Could one cause any intermittent problem than the other?

Which is preferred and why?

Lock is passed in:

```
import logging
import threading
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='(%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',
                    )

def lock_holder(lock):
    logging.debug('Starting')
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            logging.debug('Holding')
            time.sleep(0.5)
        finally:
            logging.debug('Not holding')
            lock.release()
        time.sleep(0.5)
    return

def worker(lock):
    logging.debug('Starting')
    num_tries = 0
    num_acquires = 0
    while num_acquires < 3:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        logging.debug('Trying to acquire')
        have_it = lock.acquire(0)
        try:
            num_tries += 1
            if have_it:
                logging.debug('Iteration %d: Acquired',  num_tries)
                num_acquires += 1
            else:
                logging.debug('Iteration %d: Not acquired', num_tries)
        finally:
            if have_it:
                lock.release()
    logging.debug('Done after %d iterations', num_tries)


lock = threading.Lock()

holder = threading.Thread(target=lock_holder, args=(lock,), name='LockHolder')
holder.setDaemon(True)
holder.start()

worker = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(lock,), name='Worker')
worker.start()
```

Lock not passed in and access globally:

```
import logging
import threading
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='(%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',
                    )

def lock_holder():
    logging.debug('Starting')
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            logging.debug('Holding')
            time.sleep(0.5)
        finally:
            logging.debug('Not holding')
            lock.release()
        time.sleep(0.5)
    return

def worker():
    logging.debug('Starting')
    num_tries = 0
    num_acquires = 0
    while num_acquires < 3:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        logging.debug('Trying to acquire')
        have_it = lock.acquire(0)
        try:
            num_tries += 1
            if have_it:
                logging.debug('Iteration %d: Acquired',  num_tries)
                num_acquires += 1
            else:
                logging.debug('Iteration %d: Not acquired', num_tries)
        finally:
            if have_it:
                lock.release()
    logging.debug('Done after %d iterations', num_tries)


lock = threading.Lock()

holder = threading.Thread(target=lock_holder), name='LockHolder')
holder.setDaemon(True)
holder.start()

worker = threading.Thread(target=worker, name='Worker')
worker.start()
```

Comment: There's probably a slight amount of extra overhead passing the lock as an argument, but it does avoid using global variables, which many consider a poor practice. Otherwise results should be identical.

Comment: @martineau when the locks are passed in to threads, there seems to be a  race condition but when locks are accessed globally, there arent any race condition. Even if the locks are passed in amongst threads, they are looking at the same lock, or no?

Comment: Yes, all threads should be using the same lock if it was passed to them as an argument. You can verify that making sure they all have the same `id()`. The race condition may be caused by the lock not be acquired somewhere it should have been. The fact that it appears to happen or not happen in one or the other scenario could simply be random timing variances.